# Unlimited children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I have a parent component that has a child component.
I'm limited to calling only one child inside the parent, like that:

```
<Parent child={<Child />} />
```

I wanted to render many child components inside the parent component, not just one. Something like that:

```
<Parent><Child /><Child /><Child /></Parent>
```

How can I do that?

This is my current code:

```
interface ParentProps {
  child: ReactNode;
}
const Parent = ({ child }: ParentProps) => (
  <div>
       {child}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create unlimited children,that doesn't make any sense and javascript won't allow a loop to run for infinity.But you can do something like this

**App.js**

```
import Child from "./Child";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const childArray = () => {
    const container = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {//you can put 1000 or hundred thousand whatever you want 
      container.push(<Child key={index} />);
    }
    return container;
  };

  return <div className="App">{childArray()}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

**Child.js**

```
import React from "react";

function Child() {
  return <div>This is Child component</div>;
}

export default Child;
```